# Can not drag a item being inside drop zone when have a dragend event is fired outside dopr zone

Tags: javascript

I have two div tags inside a drop zone where two div tags can move in here. But when I drag one div tag outside drop zone and drop it outside drop zone, I couldn't drag other div tag as well as interact with it.
I think that I can fix this problem by dragend event, but I don't know how do I do it.
Thanks

Comment: Where is the code ?

Comment: :) My code is so long because it is a child part of a project, so I don't know how do I show it, but I will try do it. My above question is a general question, can you help me?

Comment: No need to give that peace of code! you can set an another example.

Comment: Ok I will try do it, but I have more information, my drop zone is a iframe which is embeddeded in mian page, when I drag a item and drop it in main page (outside of iframe), all item which are existing in iframe will be unfocused (it mean all behaviors of mouse will be disabled)